# Get milisecond from Timestamp im Impala

Tags: timestamp, impala

I have a query wherein I need to extract timestamp with milliseconds to match data from Source. 
Below is sample data from SQL server (Source) and column is defined as Datetime

U_Date
2007-10-26 10:07:00.000
2005-05-04 11:12:54.297
2004-05-29 03:56:24.792

Target is Hadoop through Impala and defined as Timestamp

U_Date
2007-10-26 10:07:00
2005-05-04 11:12:54.297000000
2013-05-31 04:07:00
2013-11-01 15:34:00

I am looking for query to get timestamp as displayed in Source with millisecond. 
I have put together my query as under, but it defaults milliseconds to 000.

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(u_date),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from table A

Generated result set is as below:

2007-10-26 10:07:00.000
2005-05-04 11:12:54.000 (Millisecond .297 defaulted to 000)
2013-05-31 04:07:00.000
2013-11-01 15:34:00.000

Kindly share your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a formatted timestamp up to 3 digit milliseconds, you can use the `from_timestamp` function

```
SELECT from_timestamp(u_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') FROM table;
```

the function `unix_timestamp` somehow discards the millisecond information while the function `from_unixtime` doesn't seem to interpret unix timestamps with milliseconds well either

(tested on `Impala v2.9.0`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Unix Timestamp stored in your Database with milliseconds

> Something like this 1525245791828

and you want to remove the milliseconds from this field so that you can do Unix Timestamp comparisons.

You can do something like this:

```
cast((you_unix_timestamp_with_milliseconds_column/1000) as BIGINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use milliseconds_add or microseconds_add with from_unixtime(0),
e.g.

```
select milliseconds_add(from_unixtime(0), your_unix_timestamp_with_milliseconds_column) ;
select microseconds_add(from_unixtime(0), your_unix_timestamp_with_microseconds_column) ;
```